# How do I send emails in Java?

Tags: java, email, email-validation, email-client, mail-server

Hey. I currently want to develop a simple program in Java that sends out email. Not just a few emails, but actually a lot (10k+)
I have a subscribers list that all agree to it, by the way.

Anyway, I cannot send these emails via Gmail or anything like that - They do not allow that many emails to be sent. So the basic question is: How do I send emails by making the actual sending computer an email server?

I'm sure I should use some libraries, I heard about ChillKat or something like that.

Could anyone explain / help me out? Would be very much appreciated.

Comment: One would be curious as to what the purpose of a "small program to send out 10K+ emails" is. I can think of a number of unsavory reasons, but no legitimate ones...

Comment: sending 10K mails isn't a problem - but delivering 10K mails certainly is. Bulk mailings from an SMTP server without any mail delivering reputation will very likely be treated as spam. You should look at providers like sendgrid.com, authsmtp.com, smtp.com ...

Comment: M. Jessup, I can think of many legitimate uses.
I have a website where people can sign up for my newsletter.
I would like to send emails to everyone, but the normal services for sending 10-50k emails out are too expensive for me, so I'd rather code it myself, if not only to save money then also to learn how it works.

Answer (score 3):

- the library - [commons-email](http://commons.apache.org/email/), built ontop of the harder to use [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/)
- the servers

  - [James](http://james.apache.org/) - java based
  - [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) - for unix/linux ([howto](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html))
  - many more - there are many smtp servers. Each requires some non-trivial configurations before you can use it in production. It is better to turn to an administrator for this.

Comment: you should probably add Java Mail API. Although commons-email is built on top of it, it certainly is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

James is a very powerful email server base on Java which with you can use the [JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/). Moreover James integrate the [mailet API](http://james.apache.org/mailet/api/index.html) which is very usefull to improve the functionality of your mail server.
You can configure it to set the gateway on gmail easily changing the config file. (see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872287/problem-in-sending-external-mails-in-james-mail-server/2318873#2318873))

You can find a very good tuto here about James and mailet: [Working with James](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-james1.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, I'll look into it.
I'm kinda thinking that it might be easier to simply send the emails through gmail, even though they only allow 500 emails per day, I could just use 100 gmail accounts?